# Please explain error in understanding of backtracking recursion

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I am trying to solve [#78 Leetcode (Subsets)](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/) using backtracking recursion.
The idea is to create all possible combinations by either selecting the value at index 'i' or not selecting the value and then recursing through till the end of the list.

I wrote this code:

```
nums = [1,2,3]
res,r = [],[]
def bts(nums,r,i):
  if(i == len(nums)):
    print(i,r)
    res.append(r)
    return
  r.append(nums[i])
  print(i,r)
  bts(nums,r,i+1)
  print(i,r)
  r = r[:-1]
  print(i,r)
  bts(nums,r,i+1)
  print(i,r)
  return

bts(nums,r,0)
print(res)
```

The various `print(i,r)` lines are written to debug and see where my algorithm goes wrong. I noticed that after `[1,2]` gets pushed through to the subset when `bts(nums,[1,2],3)` is called, the return statement at the end returns to `i=1` iteration with the `(i,r)` value as `(1,[1,2,3])` instead of `(1,[1,2])`. I am unable to understand why this is so.

Comment: If the recursion has `i=3`, it has to return to `i=2`, not `i=1`.

Comment: It's confusing that you use the same variable `r` for the parameter and the global variable. Maybe that's part of your problem.

Comment: I got the code to work. I had to make a couple of changes:

1. Replace res.append(r) with res.append(r.copy())
2. Instead of r = r[:-1], I used r.pop().

I don't understand the 2nd point though. What exactly is the difference between the two commands.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work. I had to make a couple of changes:

1. Replace res.append(r) with res.append(r.copy())
2. Instead of r = r[:-1], I used r.pop().

I don't understand the 2nd point though. Why does r.pop() work but not r = r[:-1].